# How to select all records where sum of one of fields for these records equals specified value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Could you please help to create query which will do next:

I have table

```
  ID             Amount     Name    
 -----------------------------------
   1              100       Name1                
   2              50        Name2
   3              60        Name3
   4              10        Name4
   5              70        Name5
   6              10        Name6
```

I need to select all records in any set where sum of amount = 70

Any of results below will correct

1.

```
  ID             Amount     Name    
 -----------------------------------
   5              70        Name5
```

2.

```
  ID             Amount     Name    
 -----------------------------------
   2              50        Name2
   4              10        Name4
   6              10        Name5
```

3.

```
  ID             Amount     Name    
 -----------------------------------
   3              60        Name3
   6              10        Name6
```

4.

```
  ID             Amount     Name    
 -----------------------------------
   3              60        Name3
   4              10        Name4
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would like to work with first result

```
SELECT MAX(ID) [ID], SUM(Amount) [Amount], Name FROM <table>
    GROUP BY Name HAVING SUM(Amount) = 70
```

**EDIT :** use of window functions

```
select ID, Amount, Name from
(
    select ID, 
       Amount,
      Name,
      SUM(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) [Sum] from <table>
) a where Sum = 80
```

Comment: Sorry, but no. If I use 80 instead of 70 - it should be set of records with IDs 3, 4, 6. But your query return nothing in this case.